# Converting a String to Object

Tags: java

How can I convert a String to Object? Actually, I want to set

```
clientSession.setAttribute("username", "abc")
```

However, it shows

```
java.lang.String given, required java.lang.Object.
```

Comment: A String is an Object. Every class is a subclass of Object.

Comment: What made you ask this question? What are you trying to achieve? Maybe someone could still help.

Comment: Thanks. However, when I am giving input clientSession.setAttribute("username"), it shows java.lang.String given, required java.lang.Object.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct number of arguments. Most `session.setAttribute(...)` calls take two arguments, a String key and a String or Object value.

Comment: Sorry, I do it mistakenly on a hurry.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A Java `String` **is** an `Object`.  ([`String` extends `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).)

So you can get an `Object` reference via assignment/initialisation:

```
String a = "abc";
Object b = a;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, when I am giving input clientSession.setAttribute("username"), it shows java.lang.String given, required java.lang.Object.

Comment: @Arpssss: Please edit your question to include some code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3):

String extends Object, which means an Object. `Object o = a;` If you really want to get as Object, you may do like below.

```
String s = "Hi";

Object a =s;
```

Answer (score -1):

A String is a type of Object. So any method that accepts Object as parameter will surely accept String also. Please provide more of your code if you still do not find a solution.